# Why is np.dot not (at least) 10 times longer when I have 10 times more lines in the matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization

I am trying to parallelize some matrix operation using PyCUDA and to do it I compare to what python does.

But I have a result I really don't understand. When I multiply by 10 the number of lines of my matrix A in the matrix product A*B, the computation time is not multiplied by 10 the most of the time.

Take this code :

```
import time
import numpy as np

nb_traces=pow(10,1) # Nb lines
nb_samples=100 # Nb columns

a_cpu=np.ones((nb_traces,nb_samples)).astype(np.float32)
b_cpu=np.ones((nb_samples,2)).astype(np.float32)

t1PythonBegin=time.clock()
c_cpu=np.dot(a_cpu,b_cpu)
t1PythonEnd=time.clock()

print(t1PythonEnd-t1PythonBegin)
print(c_cpu.shape)
print(" ")
nb_traces=pow(10,2) # Nb lines of A : 10 times bigger than before
nb_samples=100 # Nb colonnes

a_cpu=np.ones((nb_traces,nb_samples)).astype(np.float32)
b_cpu=np.ones((nb_samples,2)).astype(np.float32)

t1PythonBegin=time.clock()
c_cpu=np.dot(a_cpu,b_cpu)
t1PythonEnd=time.clock()

print(t1PythonEnd-t1PythonBegin)
print(c_cpu.shape)
```

When I run it, I have the same order of magnitude for the two computations.

Here are the outputs I had for example :

The first line is the computation time when I have 10^1 lines in A and the second is when I have 10^2 lines (I also displayed the shape of A under the time computation).

Simu 1 :

```
3.120985184068559e-05
(10, 2)

9.086412319447845e-06
(100, 2)
```

Simu 2 :

```
3.358022058819188e-05
(10, 2)

3.0024667466932442e-05
(100, 2)
```

Simu 3 :

```
1.6987641174637247e-05
(10, 2)

1.7777763787307777e-05
(100, 2)
```

Sometimes the computation time is even faster for 10 times more lines !

How do you explain this ? I really don't understand... Indeed I have 10 times more coefficient to compute if I have 10 times more lines in the matrix A. So the program should be 10 times longer (as nothing is parallelized).

Comment: It looks like the actual computation takes a lot less time than the overhead. For me the computation time only starts to scale with the number of lines at about 10^3 lines.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple reasons for this. First, as [Swier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800086/swier) has pointed out, the overhead to the function (the stuff Python does before actually calling the function) takes more time than the function itself.

However, for large inputs, there is a second and more important matter: Numpy uses something called a [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) to do matrix operations. If your BLAS is so configured (especially if you're using Anaconda, which automatically does this for you), it **will** parallelize the code for you, even if you don't do it yourself.